# I have an error trying to subscribe to multiple topics, between them there are two of the same type, this is the error, please what can I do?

Tags: ros-kinetic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import serial
import rospy
import message_filters
import numpy as np

from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Float32


class adq_datos(object):
        def __init__(self):
                self.datos = 0

                self.pwm = message_filters.Subscriber('/PWM', Float32)
                self.encoder = message_filters.Subscriber('/enc_data', Odometry)
                self.gps = message_filters.Subscriber('/gps', Float32)
                self.imu = message_filters.Subscriber('/mti/sensor/imu_free', Imu)

                self.ts = message_filters.TimeSynchronizer([self.pwm, self.encoder, self.gps, self.imu], 10)
                self.ts.registerCallback(self.synchronize_data)
                rospy.spin()

        def synchronize_data(self, data):
                self.datos = data.pose.covariance[5]
                print self.datos

if __name__=='__main__':
        try:
                rospy.init_node('save_data',anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)
                print "Nodo Creado"
                cv = adq_datos()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
                pass
```

this is the error that show

```
[ERROR] [1576621538.678741]: bad callback: <bound method Subscriber.callback of <message_filters.Subscriber object at 0x75b23850>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 75, in callback
    self.signalMessage(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 57, in signalMessage
    cb(*(msg + args))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 216, in add
    my_queue[msg.header.stamp] = msg
AttributeError: 'Float32' object has no attribute 'header'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340276/i-have-an-error-trying-to-subscribe-to-multiple-topics,-between-them-there-are-two-of-the-same-type,-this-is-the-error,-please-what-can-i-do-?/) by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand [the `message_filter`](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filter) correctly, the messages that you're using need to have a header because

> [The `TimeSequencer` filter](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Sequencer) guarantees that messages will be called in temporal order according to their header's timestamp.

A [`Float32` message](https://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float32.html) only has a `data` field and no header. Since it's expecting a header where there isn't one, it throws an error. You'll need to use a message type that has a header.

Edit:

Also look into using [an `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer`](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) which

> uses current ROS time in place of any missing `header.stamp` field:

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on 2019-12-30**:
Thank you!, published this tipic with a message type that had Header, use Odometry for this case and works well thanks.